# Writing all lines of finger command

Tags: python, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm new to Python/ raspberry pi.  I'm trying to write all lines of the `finger` command to my web server. My code is written such a way that it only returns the second line.

see my code below:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import datetime
import pytz
import subprocess


then=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)  
TempString=str(then.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')))
TempString=TempString+"</br>" 

print("The following is the result of the Terminal 
Command 
$finger…")
p=subprocess.Popen("finger", shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
 print(line)
 TempStringF=line
retval=p.wait()


print("The following is the string stored in 
TempStringF")
print(TempStringF)
print("Opening WWW Index File for Writing…")

file=open('/var/www/html/index.html','w')
file.write(TempString)
file.write(str(TempStringF))
file.close()

print("Index file has been updated and closed…")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is where the problem is:

```
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
    TempStringF=line
```

Each time the loop runs, `TempStringF` will be overwritten by the new contents of `line`. Instead, declare your accumulation variable as an empty string outside the loop, then append to it in the loop:

```
temp_string_f = ""      # recommended style in Python is snake_case, not CapsCase
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
    temp_string_f += line + "<br>"
```

Comment: The following is the result of the terminal Command $finger...
b'Login     Name       Tty      Idle  Login Time   Office     Office Phone\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/LAB4part2.py", line 18, in <module>
    TempStringF =line+""
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: I added .encode to clear the error, but I'm still only printing one line

Comment: 2020-06-08 23:45:44.025504-04:00
pi *tty1 6d Jun 6 14:18

Comment: I just edited my answer, because I made a dumb error. The last line should be `temp_string_f += line + "<br>"`, using `+=` instead of `=`. **Now** it should work as expected...